# How can I make sure PHP is using TBinaryProtocolAccelerated

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2, thrift

How can I make sure PHP is using `TBinaryProtocolAccelerated` and not `TBinaryProtocol` as the protocol?

I am using PHP5 in Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBinaryProtocolAccelerated and TBinaryProtocol are specific to Thrift, not the PHP itself.

Have a look at https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP. What you need to do is use TBinaryProtocolAccelerated class instead of TBinaryProtocol.

Hope this helps.